# How to make my DataFrame.plot subplots posted in line?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, subplot

I'm trying to understand how pandas.DataFrame.plot works, but stuck on placing several subplots in a line. I feel pretty confused, so probably my question will sound weird. But I would be grateful for any help.

```
recent_grads.plot(x = "Women", y = "Median", kind = "scatter", subplots = True, figsize=(6, 6), layout = (2,2), sharex = False)
recent_grads.plot(x = "Men", y = "Median", kind = "scatter", subplots = True, figsize=(6, 6), layout = (2,2), sharex = False)
```

I'm getting my subplots on under another, but I want them in line.

Comment: By that, you mean they are currently aligned as one column with multiple rows, but you want them as one row with multiple columns?

Comment: Exactly, I want these two plots in one row and two columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to modify `layout`:

```
recent_grads.plot(x = "Women", y = "Median", kind = "scatter", subplots = True, figsize=(6, 6), layout = (1, 1), sharex = False)
recent_grads.plot(x = "Men", y = "Median", kind = "scatter", subplots = True, figsize=(6, 6), layout = (1, 2), sharex = False)
```

Another way is to create `Axes` objects and specify them explicitly:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, figsize=(6, 6))

ax1, ax2 = axes

recent_grads.plot(x = "Women", y = "Median", kind = "scatter", ax=ax1)
recent_grads.plot(x = "Men", y = "Median", kind = "scatter", ax=ax2)
```

Comment: Thank you, gmds, I don't get why but first option didn't work, but second works!

Answer (score 1):

u can use `plt.subplots` from `matplotlib.pyplot`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2)
fig.set_size_inches(6, 6)
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.2)
recent_grads.plot(x = "Women", y = "Median", kind = "scatter", ax=ax[0], sharex = False)
recent_grads.plot(x = "Men", y = "Median", kind = "scatter", ax=ax[1], sharex = False)
```

Comment: Thanks, but, unfortunately, they are still one above another. I even pasted your code to a new cell, but I still get the same